# Runge-Kutta 4th order for predator-prey model

Tags: python-2.7, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I want to solve a predator-prey model (Lotka-Volterra equations) with 4th order Runge-kutta method, but I don't know how to calculate the k's coefficients, my question isn't about programming (I even wrote a program to calculate the temporal evolution using Euler's method) but about maths, may someone explain me please?

Sorry if I don't post the equations, that's due I haven't the reputation enough to insert images.

Comment: You can include the equations as you used them in the Euler code. Use indentation for code formatting, or <ctrl>+K. By using the search function, you can find several posts discussing the implementation of RK4 for systems or higher order equations (via their first-order systems). Try them and report back on further problems. What exactly about the maths is unclear, do you understand the idea of using vectors reps. `numpy.array` for the state vector of the system?

Comment: *my question isn't about programming* – … which pretty much makes it off-topic on this site. Your question is probably suited for [scicomp.se], but when you ask there please include your equations (you will have MathJax available to typeset these) and particularly elaborate what you do not understand.